# Add tool tip to column headers

Tags: acumatica

Is there any way in acumatica to add a tool tip for a grid column header? I tried adding the tool tip property for the rowtemplate as it is not available for gridcolumn, but doesn't help.

```
<RowTemplate>
      <px:PXDropDown ID="edDocType" runat="server" DataField="DocType" CommitChanges="True" ToolTip="test">
      </px:PXDropDown>
</RowTemplate>
```

The above code works when the grid is in Form View, but how to give it for a column header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get this is to go to **Customization** open your **grid's column** go to **Properties** turn off **Filter** find section **Header** open it and set **Tooltip** like as in the screen:
[image]

As the result you will get such **Tooltip** for **Grids Column**

[image]